# Using Vagrant, access app on host machine from inside Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, pow

I am running a Wordpress app inside a Vagrant box that needs to access a Rails app running on my host machine (using Pow). How do I do that?

I can access the Rails app on my host machine using myapp.dev and would like to access it from  inside Vagrant as well, in the best case using the same domain.

All info I could find on that topic is about the other way around, where you want to access an app running inside Vagrant from the host machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it just sounds like you need a host entry on your guest machine pointing back your host machine?

You could do something like the following:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    require 'socket'
    local_ip = UDPSocket.open {|s| s.connect("64.233.187.99", 1); s.addr.last}
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo \"#{local_ip} myapp.dev\" >> /etc/hosts"
end
```

This should use a socket to get your host machines IP address and then using a shell provisioner it will append that IP address to your hosts file which should allow your VM to use the domain name you want to communicate with your host OS.

Comment: Works beautifully! Could you explain what the `local_id` line does? I guess it connects to Google and then looks up the addresses that the request went through, the IP of the host machine being the last one?

Comment: Also, would I need to tinker with `Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup` before opening the socket, like here? https://codeclimate.com/github/fgrehm/vagrant-notify/Vagrant::Notify::Action::InstallCommand

Comment: To be really honest I dont know the full details of what it is doing... but yes basically it is just firing a UDP packet to Google and through that connection it is working out the string of IP's involved... the last of which is the local IP... sorry I'm not really sure about the reverse lookup stuff either...

Comment: Ok, thanks! I added the reverse lookup commands as well, can't hurt. :)